# !int.TryParse What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a pretty easy assignment.
I have a textbox and a button, if the user fills in a number it'll check if it's the correct number. Now I want to make sure that the user input is a number, if it's not then I want a message box to appear that ask to fill in a number. I made the following code but it's giving me an error when i fill in a letter in the textbox. Why?

```
        private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number
        number = Convert.ToInt32(numberTb.Text);

        if (!int.TryParse(numberTb.Text, out number)){
            MessageBox.Show("This isn't a number");
        } else if (number == 3) {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
        } else if (number < 3) {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect, number must be higher");
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect, number must be lower");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is due to `Convert.ToInt32`, you don't need that, just comment that out. `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception if the conversion fails.

Comment: It's the `Convert.ToInt32`.  Why convert before checking?  Note that `Convert.ToInt32` and `int.Parse` do basically the same thing if you're passing in a `string`.  And of course `int.TryParse` just does that without throwing an exception.

Comment: Might be a bit a newb, but if i do number = (numberTb.text) it won't accept that kind of code

Comment: @DirkHeijnen Don't do that either, the `int.TryParse` will set `number` if the string you pass to it is in the correct format.  That's why it's an `out` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TryParse` doesn't just return whether the string can be converted to an integer. It actually does the conversion, and puts the result in the `out` parameter.

Therefore, you don't need a `Convert.ToInt32` call before calling `TryParse`.

You got an exception because `Convert.ToInt32` *will* throw an exception if the string is invalid. Basically, your program terminated because of `Convert.ToInt32` before it even reaches `TryParse`.

So, remove the `Convert.ToInt32` line.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that TryParse did the conversion, it cleared up a lot for me

Comment: @DirkHeijnen You can read more about it here! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you want an alternative way to check if a string is nothing but numbers, you can try: mystring.All(char.IsDigit)